# How do I unbind all instances of an event handler? Why doesn't -= remove all the instances?

Tags: c#, jquery, events

Consider this snippet:

```
class Foo
{
    public event Action Event;
    public void TriggerEvent()
    {
        if (Event != null) {
            Event();
        }
    }
}

static void Handler()
{
    Console.WriteLine("hi!");
}

static void Main()
{
    var obj = new Foo();
    obj.Event += Handler;
    obj.Event += Handler;
    obj.TriggerEvent();
    Console.WriteLine("---");
    obj.Event -= Handler;
    obj.TriggerEvent();
}
```

The output I get:

```
hi!
hi!
---
hi!
```

The last "hi!" was quite unexpected. To remove it I have to call `Event -= Handler;` one more time. But what if I don't know how many times handler was bound?

**UPDATE:** Would be interesting to know the reasons behind this a bit counterintuitive behavior: *why* doesn't `-=` remove all the instances?

**UPDATE 2:** I realized that I find this behavior counterintuitive because of the difference with jQuery.

```
var handler = function() { console.log('hi!'); }, obj = {};
$(obj).on("event", handler).on("event", handler).trigger("event");
console.log("---");
$(obj).off("event", handler).trigger("event");
```

Output:

```
hi!
hi!
---
```

Comment: try this solution [Removing Event Handlers using Reflection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103542/Removing-Event-Handlers-using-Reflection)

Comment: @thorn - They're different instances. They may look the same, but they're not.

Comment: @RitchMelton But the `-=` operator doesn't care about their identities when it decides which one to remove. It just removes a first one that equals to its argument by value.

Comment: @RitchMelton And even if an instance is single, but just is bound multiple times, it still can't be unbound by one `-=` call.

Comment: @thorn - I understand the (default) mechanism. I was just responding to the counterintuitive part. I don't find it counterintuitive given that they are different instances.

Comment: @RitchMelton see my 'update 2' re counterintuitiveness

Comment: @HenkHolterman I can think of use cases for the jQuery behaviour, but can't do so for the C# one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand why you might consider your example to be counter-intuitive.

Consider this modification

```
var del = new Action(Handler);
obj.Event += del;
obj.Event += del;
obj.TriggerEvent();
Console.WriteLine("---");
obj.Event -= del;
obj.TriggerEvent();
```

It works exactly the same as yours, but why?

When you used

```
obj.Event += Handler
```

The compiler did something behind your back. It created a new instance of `Action(Handler)` three times (two add, one remove). In the modification we use exactly the same delegate object.

So the real question is: In your example, why did the remove even work? You're passing an object to remove that wasn't used to add. The answer is that delegates have value equality.

```
var del1 = new Action(Handler);
var del2 = new Action(Handler);
Console.WriteLine("Reference equal? {0}, Value equal? {1}", Object.ReferenceEquals(del1, del2), del1.Equals(del2));
// Reference equal? False, Value equal? True
```

So now you might be thinking, "Why were two event handlers added? Shouldn't there be only one since they are the same handler?"

The answer is, "No". A multi-cast delegate doesn't care if you add the same handler multiple times, it's not a set, it's a list.

When you removed one handler, it recognized that there are two identical handlers in its list and removed one of them.

Comment: I thought that 'reference equality' and 'identity equality' are the same thing. And that what you call 'identity equality' is called 'equality by value'. Where can I read up on these terms?

Comment: @thorn I probably should have said "reference equality" and "value equality". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183752.aspx

Answer (score 1):

try this solution [Removing Event Handlers using Reflection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103542/Removing-Event-Handlers-using-Reflection)

or

```
 Delegate[] dellist = myEvent.GetInvocationList();
    foreach (Delegate d in v)
           myEvent-= (d as MyDelegate);//MyDelegate is type of delegate
```

Answer (score 1):

Delegates combine all handlers that you assign to it. If you assign the same handler twice it will be called twice and has to be removed twice. I don't think this is counterintuitive.

If you have control over the class that defines the event you can use something like the following to remove all instances of a specific handler at once:

```
private Action _Event;

public event Action Event
{
    add
    {
        _Event += value;
    }
    remove
    {
        while (_Event != null && _Event.GetInvocationList().Contains(value))
        {
            _Event -= value;
        }
    }
}
```

If you do not have control over the event then you have to accept that the `-=` operator removes only one instance of the handler. This is by design of the language and can not be changed.

It is like adding the same string to a `List<string>` multiple times. If you want to remove all instances of that string you have to call the Remove method multiple times.

I would not recommend the above code if your `Foo` class will be used by others because it behaves different from any other class.

Answer (score 0):

Delegates should be "wrapped" in events like instances fields are wrapped in properties. Then you can control them.

```
public class Test
{
    public class Foo
    {
        private Action _event;
        public event Action Event
        {
            add { _event += value; }
            remove { _event -= value; }
        }

        public void DoEvent()
        {
            if (_event != null)
                _event ();
        }

        public void ClearEvent()
        {
            _event = null;
        }
    }

    static void Handler() {
        Console.WriteLine("hi!");
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();

        foo.Event += Handler;
        foo.Event += Handler;
        foo.DoEvent();
        Console.WriteLine("---");

        foo.ClearEvent();

        foo.DoEvent();

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: But I don't need to remove all handlers at all. Just a specific handler that can be bound multiple times.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to do this.  `event Action MyEvent` is equivalent to an auto-property, but allows you do access the field too.

Answer (score -2):

```
Event = Delegate.RemoveAll(Event, handler);
```

Note that this is not thread-safe, and that it will only work within the class that declares the event.

Comment: I replaced `Handler` everywhere with `var handler = new Action(Handler);` for this to be compiled. And discovered that this line doesn't have any effect at all.